# What is an event broker? and how do you configure one on windows 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying without complete success to create a wso2 identity server on a windows server 2008 vm. I followed the online instructions and installed the pre-requisits (jre and jdk), downloaded the zip file, setup the environment variables, and ran the wso2server.bat file. There were a lot of errors.

I then realized I needed to add active directory role on the server, which I did. It still wouldn't install. I did some more online research which led me to believe I needed to install wso2 esb as well, which I did. I was able to get that install to work and was able to create a desktop app to consume the web services. All well and good. but then as part of the requirements they wanted to enable passive sts with an asp.net client (not really sure what that is), so I went back to the identity server and am still getting errors while running the bat file, though I an able to run the gui from the browser, but unable to log in.

The exception I am getting is :

TID: [0] [IS] [2013-10-07 10:34:58,746] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.builder.EventBrokerHandler} - Can not create the event broker {org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.builder.EventBrokerHandler} org.wso2.carbon.event.core.exception.EventBrokerConfigurationException: Can not access the user registry

in addition, I am also getting authentication errors on some of the esb web calls, but not all, and I would also like to know how to change from the default user store (ldap or ad or whatever it is) to sql server.

I have seen a few examples for doing it with mysql and oracle, but not sql server, specific product information is sometimes challenging to find.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks. Mike

Comment: Are using Identity Server 4.5.0? if not can you please mention the version you are using.